# ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID returns NULL when contact has linked contacts

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, abrecord

I have no problem getting common contacts (which don't have a linked contact)

but as soon i pick a linked contact using

```
- (void)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController*)peoplePicker didSelectPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {
```

and than want to retrive the ABRecordRef

```
ABRecordRef recordRef = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(self.wrapper.ref, recordID.intValue);
```

i always get null, when the contact is a linked contact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the AB methods are deprecated on iOS9 and in contrary to iOS8 and 7, `ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID` doesn't work for linked contacts on iOS9 (works on 7-8)

so the solution is to switch to the CN methods introduced in iOS9